# How to convert List<Object> to JSON on playframework Java

Tags: java, view, playframework-2.0, json

First of all, I am using playframework 2 with Java.

I have a Bootstrap-lookahead input field in a view and I want to use a json array as source for it, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/1866577).
I can generate json at server-side with:

```
Json.toJson(users)
```

or on client with:

```
@{Json.toJson(users)}
```

However it generates strings with `&quot;` and when I try to create the bootstrap-lookahead field with this data, it gives me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Could someone help me with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent escaping by using `@Html(Json.toJson(users))` in template.

[Docs, last paragraph](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplates)